# How to invalidate an input in c

Tags: c

I'm writing a program in C that is suppose to ask the user for a number.

The number has to be greater than zero and cannot have letters before or after the number. (ie: `400` is valid but `abc` or `400abc` or `abc400` is not). I can make my program invalidate everything besides `400abc`. How would I make it invalidate an input if it starts valid then turns invalid? (I'm about 2 months into an intro to c class so my knowledge is very limited.)

```
    #include<stdio.h>

int check(void);
void clear_input(void);

main()
{
    int num;
    printf("Please enter a number: ");

    num = check();
    printf("In Main %d\n", num);

}

int check(void){

    int c;

    scanf("%d", &c);
    while (c < 0){
        clear_input();
        printf("Invalid, please enter an integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &c);
    }

    return c;
}

void clear_input(void){
    char junk;
    do{
        scanf("%c", &junk);
    }while (junk != '\n');
}
```

Comment: What's your question?  What have you tried?  What have you found not to work?  (And is this homework?)

Comment: There are easily a dozen ways to do this.  You should be able to think of at least one.

Comment: As a note, your program is not checking the second thing entered. You should do `return check();` after your `printf("Invalid, please enter an integer: ");`, and not `scanf("%d", &c);`.

Comment: It is homework. I need to get my program to check if an input is valid and then ask the user to re-input if its not valid. My question is how do I say an input is invalid if it starts valid but then turns invalid.

Answer (score 6):

You can also check whether ascii value of each char scanned from user input should lie in range 48-57, It will only then be integer value.

Comment: It's far better to check of the input lies in the range of `'0'` to `'9'` than to use the explicit ASCII decimal values.  While `'0'` is equivalent to `48`, the former avoids magic constants, providing better documentation for what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

`strtol` can be used to do it, but it takes some extra work.

After running this code:

```
char *endptr;
int n = strtol(num_text, &endptr, 10);
```

`n` will contain the number. But you still have to check that:
1. `*endptr=='\0'` - this means `strtol` didn't stop in the middle. In `400abc`, `endptr` will point to `abc`. You may want to allow trailing whitespace (in this case, check that `endptr` points to an all-whitespace string.
2. `num_text` isn't empty. In this case, `strtol` will return 0, but an empty string isn't a valid number.

Answer (score 0):

Read the input as a line, using `fgets`.

Check if all characters are numeric.

If not, it's invalid. If yes, use `sscanf` to get the line into an int.

Check if the int is in the range; you're done.

Comment: I'd use fgets or sscanf we haven't learned those yet (I'm in an intro to c class).

Answer (score 0):

Scanf with %d will treat the "400abc" as 400, all the trailing characters would be ignored, so there is nothing to worry about.

If you definitely want to treat "400abc" as an invalid input, then maybe you shouldn't use %d in scanf, use %s instead?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to read the whole line as a string and check by yourself if it contains any non-digits.

The other way is reading the integer and then looking into the input using `fgetc()` to see if the next character after the detected input is valid. Or you could even use the same scanf() for this:

```
char delim;
if(scanf("%d%c", &c, &delim) == 2 && !isspace(delim))
  // the input is invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the number in a character array and validate it by checking if all the characters lie in the ascii range 48 to 57 ( '0' to '9' ) .If so your no. is valid otherwise you can safely regard it as invalid input.Here the the demonstration :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int conv( char * word )
{
    int ans=0;
    int res=0;
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(word);i++)
        if(word[i]>='0' && word[i]<='9')
            ans=(ans*10) + (word[i] - '0');
        else
            res=-999;
    if(res==-999)
        return res;
    else
        return ans;
}
int main()
{
    char a[10];
    gets(a);
    int b=conv(a);
    if(b==-999)
        printf("Invalid Entry.\n");
    else
        printf("Success.No is %d.\n",b);
    return 0;
}
```

You can adjust for negatives as well by checking the first character in the word array to be '-' and adjusting the sign accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The following is your check function rewritten to fix your problem, so try this:

```
int check(void){

    int n;
    char c;

    while (EOF==scanf("%d%c", &n,&c) || n < 0 || !isspace(c)){
        clear_input();
        printf("Invalid, please enter an integer: ");
    }

    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is C99, so compile with -std=c99

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool getNum(int *n) {
    char c, s[10];
    if (!scanf("%9s", s))
        return false;
    for (int i=0; c=s[i]; i++)
        if (!isdigit(c))
    return false; 
    *n = atoi(s);
    return true;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    if (getNum(&n))
        printf("you entered %d\n", n);
    else
        printf("you did not enter a number\n");
}
```